# Three.js and loading models from a database

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a database (MySQL) with models (FBX). Client side of my application can read models from the database. But a model data is stored in a javascript variable.

How can I use THREE.FBXLoader() to load the model data from the JavaScript variable? Of course, there is no problems to use THREE.FBXLoader() for loading models from local hard disk.

Thank you

Mike

Comment: how are you requesting the models? can't you just put the request url in the FBXLoader's load function?

Comment: I have @Stateless RESTful Service on the server side and AngulaJS + Three.js on the client side. The angular's client side have 'factory' with methof get which reads whole database record. One fieild of this record is a fbx data model.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the parse() method instead of load()

```
var _data= ... // your model datas
var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
var obj = loader.parse(_data);
```